# While screen while waking up

Tags: suspend, login-screen, white-screen

I'm using -
Discription : Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release : 20.04
5.0.4-48-generic

There is a problem, my pc sleeps out after sometime and when i try to waking it up, it shows white screen only. Nothing happens than.

Again i have to restart it and all tabs and apps get closed than it's so much time consuming to do on, off and restating all the apps again.
Please help how to fix it..

Comment: Why are you using the EOL 5.0 kernel?   or is it a typo?  (that is the kernel used by Ubuntu 19.04)

Comment: I'm new at Linux so could you please give me some suggestions which kernel i should use??

Comment: You should use the 5.4 kernel the system comes with, 5.0 was the kernel used by Ubuntu 19.04 which is now *end-of-life* and thus *unsupported* having had no security fixes since the beginning of the year. It's probable you're using 5.4 already, just made a typo typing 5.0.4 instead (where 5.0.4/5.0 is very different to 5.4.0/5.4; the first two numbers are what matters; the rest just tell you security-fixes installed)